# Fairy tale where the protagonist uses candles stuck to the back of crabs to convince someone the Rapture has happened

Tags: story-identification, fairy-tales

When I was a child, somewhere in the mid 1980s to the mid 1990s, I encountered a pamphlet describing The [Rapture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapture) (I grew up in a very Baptist part of Kentucky) which described piles of clothing found after people had disappeared, and strange lights moving around as people came to realize they were among those left behind. Around the same time, in a book of fairy tales (I want to say that it was a collection of 365 fairy tales, one for each day of the year), I remember the protagonist uses trickery to convince someone that either they'd entered the afterlife, or that angels were coming down to collect souls, by sticking lit candles on the backs of crabs, creating a random set of moving lights in the distance, but for the life of me, I can't remember which fairy tale it was. Thinking about it now, I think he uses this to allow him to kidnap some important person by convincing them to let him stuff them into a sack, whereupon he submits them to a number of tortures like being dragged down the stairs, or through cold water, with him explaining that it was actually the person in the sack being safely carried past the tortures of hell.

I remember that the collection had "The Brave Tin Soldier", "Bearskin", and "The Tinder Box", and that it was a large white-covered book, like coffee-table size but thick (which would make sense if there were indeed 365 fairy tales), but I'm chiefly trying to remember the fairy tale.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like *[The Master Thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_Thief)* by The Brothers Grimm.

Here's an excerpt from [the full tale](https://www.worldoftales.com/fairy_tales/Brothers_Grimm/Margaret_Hunt/The_Master-Thief.html#gsc.tab=0), with the most relevant sections of text bolded:

> When night had fallen he went with a long sack on his back, a bundle under his arms, and a lantern in his hand to the village-church. In the sack he had some crabs, and in the bundle short wax-candles. **He sat down in the churchyard, took out a crab, and stuck a wax-candle on his back. Then he lighted the little light, put the crab on the ground, and let it creep about.** He took a second out of the sack, and treated it in the same way, and so on until the last was out of the sack. Hereupon he put on a long black garment that looked like a monk's cowl, and stuck a gray beard on his chin. When at last he was quite unrecognizable, he took the sack in which the crabs had been, went into the church, and ascended the pulpit. The clock in the tower was just striking twelve; when the last stroke had sounded, **he cried with a loud and piercing voice, "Hearken, sinful men, the end of all things has come! The last day is at hand! Hearken! Hearken! Whosoever wishes to go to heaven with me must creep into the sack.** I am Peter, who opens and shuts the gate of heaven. Behold how the dead outside there in the churchyard, are wandering about collecting their bones. Come, come, and creep into the sack; the world is about to be destroyed!" The cry echoed through the whole village. The parson and clerk who lived nearest to the church, heard it first, and when they saw the lights which were moving about the churchyard, they observed that something unusual was going on, and went into the church. They listened to the sermon for a while, and then the clerk nudged the parson and said, "It would not be amiss if we were to use the opportunity together, and before the dawning of the last day, find an easy way of getting to heaven." "To tell the truth," answered the parson, "that is what I myself have been thinking, so if you are inclined, we will set out on our way." "Yes," answered the clerk, "but you, the pastor, have the precedence, I will follow." So the parson went first, and ascended the pulpit where the master opened his sack. The parson crept in first, and then the clerk. **The master immediately tied up the sack tightly, seized it by the middle, and dragged it down the pulpit-steps, and whenever the heads of the two fools bumped against the steps, he cried, "We are going over the mountains." Then he drew them through the village in the same way, and when they were passing through puddles, he cried, "Now we are going through wet clouds,"** and when at last he was dragging them up the steps of the castle, he cried, "Now we are on the steps of heaven, and will soon be in the outer court." When he had got to the top, he pushed the sack into the pigeon-house, and when the pigeons fluttered about, he said, "Hark how glad the angels are, and how they are flapping their wings!" Then he bolted the door upon them, and went away.